# Jquery syntax when calling methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

someMethod1();



$(function () {
    someMethod2();
});

</script>
```

What is the difference between these two callings? When do we do the first call, and when do we do the second call? What is the order of the method execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someMethod1 is executed immediately

someMethod2 waits for the whole page to load,
including external javascript files (other scripts, or from other sites), CSS
and other resources before executing the code.

```
$(function () {
    //run after page loads
});
```

Method2 sometimes comes in the form of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

For more info: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It is actually bound to the DOM ready event, meaning that it fires before all resources have loaded.  All synchronous scripts will execute prior to DOM ready, but images might not.

Answer (score 3):

```
someMethod1();
```

This might be called before or after document is ready and it does not require jQuery. If this is at the end of your page it will be called when all control are ready but if it is in middle then it will know only controls that got rendered.

```
$(function () {
    someMethod2();
});
```

This is call always after the document gets ready and all the controls are ready/rendered. This requires jQuery. You can read more about ready [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This will also help you understand the other function call.

Answer (score 1):

The statements in the script block are executed in the order in which they occur. If we number the lines and insert an extra line break or two to make it easier to talk about:

```
1  someMethod1();
2
3  $(
4    function () {
5      someMethod2();
6    }
7  );
```

Line 1, `someMethod1()` is executed first.

Then line 3, `$()` is executed, where the parameter to `$()` is an anonymous function defined on lines 4 to 6. The `$()` function schedules that anonymous function to be executed later in response to the document ready event. That is, the anonymous function is not executed at that time.

Finally, when the document is ready, the anonymous function from lines 4 to 6 is executed which means line 5 `someMethod2()` occurs.